# ReactDOM.render append instead of replace

Tags: reactjs

I've a website that I would like to extend with functionality with React. I've run into a problem that I need to add options to a menu, but the ReactDOM.render method only allows me to fully replace all contents of an HTMLElement instead of adding one.

I've tried the following:

Adding a `span` to the menu and using that element in the render method, which seems to add my menu as intended with all its functionality but breaks the entire style making it unusable.

```
const placeholder = document.createElement('span');
document.getElementById('menu')?.appendChild(placeholder);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Menu option='x' />,
  placeholder,
);
```

Doing the same but adding a callback to the render method to remove the `span` element, which breaks the functionality.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Menu option='x' />,
  placeholder,
  () => placeholder.replaceWith(...Array.from(placeholder.childNodes))
);
```

Comment: Use router for that purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the `createPortal` function. Now the element is added besides all other existing elements with seemingly no side-effects. Without the placeholder `span` it also does not screw up the style or existing navigation in javascript through properties (`parentElement`).

```
const menu = document.getElementById('menu');

menu && ReactDOM.render(
  ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <Menu option='x' />, 
    menu),
  document.createElement('div')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not render the menu and the options using react, something like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<Menu />,document.getElementById('menu_container'));

class Menu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {options.map(op => {
                    return (<MenuOption {...op} />);
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class MenuOption extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                option html
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It extends the functionality of a website, where the menu is an already existing element. So the menu and its options are not something I have control over.

Comment: well then, either you try to fix the style when adding the span, or just use jquery to add the options and the new functionality

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to other answers, **React 18** warns that you need to use createRoot instead.

You can fix it by replacing ReactDom.render with this:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

createRoot(document.getElementById('menu')).render( <Menu option='x' />)
```